# Restrict access to a page based on where they come from

Tags: php

I want to make sure that only users who have come from `anotherdomain.com/test.php` can access `mydomain.com/validate.php`.Ofcourse i can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but the referer can be easily forged .

What other verification i can put in place to make this reliable

I control both `anotherdomain.com` and `mydomain.com`

Comment: There are multiple ways without `HTTP_REFERER`. You can set query strings, Cookie, Session or Tokens to validate and allow them.

Comment: did you try to add param on your `anotherdomain.com/test.php?allowme=yes` . explode your `HTTP_REFERER`, and check for param in your validate page

Comment: @RahilWazir ...Thanks for the ideas.Could you post examples of those methods ?

Comment: Do you control both `anotherdomain.com` and `mydomain.com`?  In that you can modify the source of the pages?

Comment: @timclutton yes i control both `anotherdomain.com` and `mydomain.com`

Comment: You can't use cookies or sessions, they don't work across different domains. Tokens are what you put in the query string, cookie or session.

Comment: @Quentin could you point me to an example? ...Also can tokens be forged

Comment: The ability to forge tokens depends on too many factors to give a simple answer.

Comment: @Quentin could you show me some code where tokens are used to secure pages across domains

Comment: No. I don't have time to write a system like that now, don't know enough about your problem to know if my implementation would be relevant, and wouldn't want to do it in PHP anyway.

Comment: Since you control both sides, perhaps you could generate a hashed or encrypted value as part of the link (or a hidden value if using POST) to send as part of the request.  This would need to have a dynamic part to ensure a malicious actor couldn't just copy and paste it.

Comment: @timclutton i though of that myself + use of POST but i got stuck at the "dynamic" part because i can't think how i can make it dynamic